# Python Help: How to take input file values and pass their values in the script

Tags: python

I have a requirement where in I have to create one file which will have multiple lines and need to pass the values of the multiple lines as a variable in the python script. And also output file should be created which will display the results.

For example:

input.text : /opt/app_name/file.txt

Andy City State India

Ram City State India

Sandy City State India

Leo City State India

output.text

Andy : success

Ram : Fail

Sandy : success

Leo : Fail

When the script will be executed, it will first ask to enter the file name
Enter the file name: /opt/app_name/file.txt

Comment: Could use some more details, like what code do you have to try and do this?

Comment: When I am running the below mentioned script, I am getting an error message
" list index out of range "

Comment: file_name = raw_input('Enter the file name: ')
with file(file_name, 'r') as f:    
     file_list = f.read().strip().split('\n')
     for _f_name in file_list:
         _file_meta_list =_f_name.split(',')
         print(_file_meta_list)

Answer (score 0):

I am unsure what you are asking for, here is an attempt:

```
name  = input('Enter the file name: ')
lines = open(name).readlines()                   #Then you don't have to split over '\n'.
lines = [line.strip().split() for line in lines] #Split defaults to spaces, but you can us ',', if you need instead.

processed = []
for name,city,state,country in lines:
    success = "don't know how you are determining success"
    processed.append(name,success)

open('output_file.txt','w').write('\n'.join(' '.join(line) for line in processed))
```

Comment: Thanks Bobby for your prompt response.
I have the take input from the file and then use those values as a variable in the script.
file name is : sample.text. ( This file will have 4 lines)
So the script will take the values as the index position and pass in the script.

I am using this code in the script. However, I am getting an error message list index out of range.

def ko_update():
                 file_name = raw_input('Enter the file name: ')

Comment: Here is a code:

def ko_update():
                 file_name = raw_input('Enter the file name: ')
                 with file(file_name, 'r') as f:
             file_list = f.read().strip().split('\n')
             for _f_name in file_list:
                 _file_meta_list =_f_name.split(',')
                 print(_file_meta_list)
response = requests.post( server + '/servicccesNS/' + _file_meta_list[2] + '/' + _file_meta_list[0] + '/data/ci/lists/' + _file_meta_list[1] +"/bcc", data=data,auth=(user, password), verify=False)
        print(response.text)

Comment: Could you update your question to include your code with the correct indentations? More importantly, how would you use the text in the file as variables? Do you mean "Andy" needs to be a variable? With what value? Is "City" another variable?